# Convert nth column of CSV from EPOCH to human readable in bash

Tags: linux, bash, awk, epoch

I've tried to create a single line command to convert a particular column in a CSV from EPOCH to human readable. The file contains various columns, depending on the particular file. E.g. in this file EPOCH is in column 3 of 3, in another file it is in column 5 of 9.

```
[user@Dreadnaught log]$ cat FailedApps.log
Config, Unable to open file /var/config/snapshot.xml, 1658872997
Config, Unable to open file /var/config/snapshot.xml, 1661421388
Config, Unable to open file /var/config/snapshot.xml, 1661421414
```

The basic conversion works when done manually, so I know the values are valid EPOCH dates:

```
[user@Dreadnaught log]$ date -d@1658872997
Tue Jul 26 22:03:17 UTC 2022
```

But I'm having trouble passing item 3 to the date function correctly when I parse the file - it appears the EPOCH date gets passed with a space in front of it, which breaks the date command. Here's my attempt, learnt from other posts on this forum:

```
[user@Dreadnaught log]$ cat FailedApps.log | awk -F, '{ OFS = FS; command="date -d@\""$3"\""; command |getline; close(command); print}'
date: invalid date '@ 1658872997'
Config, Unable to open file /var/config/snapshot.xml, 1658872997
date: invalid date '@ 1661421388'
Config, Unable to open file /var/config/snapshot.xml, 1661421388
date: invalid date '@ 1661421414'
Config, Unable to open file /var/config/snapshot.xml, 1661421414
```

Please let me know how to correctly pass $3 to the date function? I tried a sed but that made it worse.

Note: `strftime` is not available in this build, and it's an embedded machine so I can't add it.

Comment: Your fields are seperated with comma AND space. By using `-F,` you are seperating on the comma. So the space is considered part of the field. 
On my Ubuntu with GNU awk I can use `-F', '` to use the combo of comma and space. Maybe that works also on your system, too?

Comment: You are using ',' as a delimiter and passing " 1661421414" to the `date`. Use default delimiter and column `$7` or `$NR`.

Comment: I wouldn't **replace** the epoch time but **ADD** a column with a human readable date because for any other processing than reading it with the eyes you'll have to reconvert it to the epoch time

Comment: @LarsFischer FYI every awk supports multi-char `FS` (which is treated as a regexp).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your fields are separated by `,`  rather than `,` inform your `awk` about that inside `BEGIN` and then `date` should start working:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=", "}{command="date -d@\""$3"\""; command |getline; close(command); print}' FailedApps.log
```

Observe that also you do not have to use `cat` as `awk` can read files on its' own.

> That is reading the 3rd column and converting it correctly, but it's
> not printing the first two columns.

You might use separate `printf` for that as follows

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=", "}{printf "%s%s%s%s",$1,OFS,$2,OFS}{command="date -d@\""$3"\""; command |getline; close(command); print}' FailedApps.log
```

Be warned that above code assumes input file with 3rd column, in order to make it work with variable number of fields you might use `for` loop which will `printf` each but last field followed by `OFS`

Comment: So close! That is reading the 3rd column and converting it correctly, but it's not printing the first two columns. I'm trying to wrangle it, but I haven't got it yet.

Comment: If `date | getline` failed for any reason that would quietly re-print the last successful value and you'd never know there had been a problem. See http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline for when/how to call `getline` and it's caveats.

Comment: @Scott I upgraded my answer

Answer (score 3):

Since you don't have GNU awk, there's no point involving awk at all, just use shell:

```
$ while IFS=',' read -r a b c; do
    printf "%s,%s,%s\n" "$a" "$b" " $(date -d@"${c# }")"
done < FailedApps.log
Config, Unable to open file /var/config/snapshot.xml, Tue Jul 26 17:03:17 CDT 2022
Config, Unable to open file /var/config/snapshot.xml, Thu Aug 25 04:56:28 CDT 2022
Config, Unable to open file /var/config/snapshot.xml, Thu Aug 25 04:56:54 CDT 2022
```

With the above we just have `shell` calling `date`, i.e. `shell { date }`, whereas if you involved `awk` it'd need to spawn a subshell to call `date` once per input line, and you'd have `shell { awk { system { subshell { date } } } }` which would be needlessly inefficient in execution time and resources.

With your other input file where the epoch value is in field 5 of 9 you'd change the above to:

```
$ while IFS=',' read -r a b c d e rest; do
    printf "%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n" "$a" "$b" "$c" "$d" " $(date -d@"${e# }")" "$rest"
done < FailedApps.log
```

Answer (score 0):

who says you need `gnu-awk`

> ```
> mawk 'BEGIN { print strftime("%D %T %z ( %s )", systime()) }'
> ```

```
10/04/22 23:52:14 -0400 ( 1664941934 )
```

But if you're not sure which `date` your system has, here's an auto detection function (tested on `mawk` `gawk` and `nawk` ) :

-- the value of `RS` at time of function calling would be properly restored by end of it

—- erroneous `getline` that failed would simply return no output instead of stale values

```
  jot - 1663041991.31215523 1664941991 191257.82822 |
```

> ```
> mawk '
> function ____(_,__,___) { 
>     return \
>     substr((___ = RS) * (RS = "\n" (__ = "")), 
>     (_=" date "(FLG_BSD_DATE ? "-r "int(_)" "    \
>                              : " -d\47@"(_)"\47 ")\
>         " +\47 %Y-%m-%d %T %Z ( %s" \
>     (FLG_BSD_DATE ? "" : ".%6N" ) " )\47")| getline __,
>     close(_) *_* (RS = ___))__ 
> } 
> BEGIN { 
>      FLG_BSD_DATE = system("exit \140date +\"%s%N"\
>                            "\" | grep -cF N \140 " )
>
> } ($++NF = ____($!_))^_' | gcat -n | lgp3 4
> ```

-- output when `gnu-date` detected :

```
 1  1663041991.31215525  2022-09-13 00:06:31 EDT ( 1663041991.312155 )
 2  1663233249.14037514  2022-09-15 05:14:09 EDT ( 1663233249.140375 )
 3  1663424506.96859503  2022-09-17 10:21:46 EDT ( 1663424506.968595 )
 4  1663615764.79681492  2022-09-19 15:29:24 EDT ( 1663615764.796814 )

 5  1663807022.62503481  2022-09-21 20:37:02 EDT ( 1663807022.625034 )
 6  1663998280.45325470  2022-09-24 01:44:40 EDT ( 1663998280.453254 )
 7  1664189538.28147459  2022-09-26 06:52:18 EDT ( 1664189538.281474 )
 8  1664380796.10969448  2022-09-28 11:59:56 EDT ( 1664380796.109694 )

 9  1664572053.93791437  2022-09-30 17:07:33 EDT ( 1664572053.937914 )
10  1664763311.76613426  2022-10-02 22:15:11 EDT ( 1664763311.766134 )
```

-- output when `bsd-date` detected :

```
 1  1663041991.31215525  2022-09-13 00:06:31 EDT ( 1663041991 )
 2  1663233249.14037514  2022-09-15 05:14:09 EDT ( 1663233249 )
 3  1663424506.96859503  2022-09-17 10:21:46 EDT ( 1663424506 )
 4  1663615764.79681492  2022-09-19 15:29:24 EDT ( 1663615764 )

 5  1663807022.62503481  2022-09-21 20:37:02 EDT ( 1663807022 )
 6  1663998280.45325470  2022-09-24 01:44:40 EDT ( 1663998280 )
 7  1664189538.28147459  2022-09-26 06:52:18 EDT ( 1664189538 )
 8  1664380796.10969448  2022-09-28 11:59:56 EDT ( 1664380796 )

 9  1664572053.93791437  2022-09-30 17:07:33 EDT ( 1664572053 )
10  1664763311.76613426  2022-10-02 22:15:11 EDT ( 1664763311 )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this trivially with the `gawk` or `mawk` time extensions to `awk` using `strftime()`. You can simply pick the last field in each record (line) using (`$NF`) and then output the date/time format however you like. See [GNU Awk User Guide - 9.1.6 Time Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html)

Using the simple `"%F %T"` format to produce `"Y-m-d H:M:S"` all you would need is:

```bash
awk '{ print strftime ("%F %T", $NF) }' FailedApps.log
```

**Example Use/Output**

With the data you show in the file `FailedApps.log`, you would get:

```
$ awk '{ print strftime ("%F %T", $NF) }' FailedApps.log
2022-07-26 17:03:17
2022-08-25 04:56:28
2022-08-25 04:56:54
```

You can change the date/time format, add a UTC offset, or add any additional output you like. Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Thanks Daweo and @Ed Morton, both solutions work. The other file with the EPOCH in field 5 of 9 has leading zeros, so it breaks the date function, but I can hack at that. Next challenge  is to get it working with tail, and ideally in an alias (I've had trouble converting a working command to an alias in the past... :/ ). I'll hack at it, and update here when I get a clean solution for the leading zeros and the alias. Thanks for your help!